# Explicit Interface Implementation with access modifiers

Tags: c#, interface

this issue is that i want DataHelper class to be internal so only same project can use that. but i am using interfaces, which dosnt not allow access modifier, what would be the approach for this. Thank you

```
public interface IDataHelper<T>{

    int Insert(T aType)
}

//implict implementation //flat insert logic
internal class ProductDataHelper : IDataHelper<Product>{

    internal int Insert(Product aType){  //cannot use internal access modifier and dont need public

        //flat insert logic

        return 1;
    }
}

//explict implementation //flat insert logic
Public class ProductDataHelper : IDataHelper<Product>{

    int IDataHelper<Product>.Insert(Product aType){ //this becomes private

        //flat insert logic

        return 1;
    }
}

//insert with business logic
public class ProductDataHandler{

    public int Add(Product aType){

        //insert with business logic
        new Insert(Product); // this is not accessable if explict interface implementation is done

        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can make the class `ProductDataHandler` and have the `Insert` method `public`. This would make the method accessible via both class and interface. And since the class is internal you can not access outside the certain boundaries so the method is also not accessible.

Comment: Did you try https://alexfranchuk.com/blog/internal-interface-classes-in-csharp/ ?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya A potential downside of that is that the class would be accessible outside the project **via the interface** - which I suspect is what the OP is trying to avoid.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya i wanted productDataHelper not to be accessible outside project and want ProductDataHandler to be accessible public, but i use interface for datahelper i have no choice but to keep datahelper public, or if interface explicitly implemented i cannot access datahelper in datahandler... :(

Comment: @mjwills its written in my question also, please look at this

`//filename ProductDataHelper.cs
//explict implementation
Public class ProductDataHelper : IDataHelper<Product>{

    int IDataHelper<Product>.Insert(Product aType){ 

        //flat insert logic
        
        return 1;
    }
}

//filename ProductDataHandler.cs
public class ProductDataHandler{

    public int Add(Product aType){

        //insert with business logic
        new Insert(Product); // this is not accessable if explict interface implementation is done

        return 1;
    }
}`

Comment: @mjwills the link you shared, looks like that is what i want, let me try that extension class example.

Answer (score 2):

The implementations of methods of an interface should be public, that's what implementing an interface means. The fact that the class is internal only means that the class is known only by the project it is declared in, but that doesn't prevent this project from instantiating that class and pass it to other projects as 'object' or as a public interface. Meanwhile you can always declare the interface itself as internal.

```
internal interface IDataHelper<T>
{
    int Insert(T aType);
}

internal class ProductDataHelper : IDataHelper<Product>
{
    public int Insert(Product aType)
    {  
        // ...
    }
}
```

**n.b.** contrary to what the comment in your question suggests, explicit implementations of an interface methods are also `public` even though the `public` key word is not present.

Comment: `explicit implementations of an interface methods are also public` It depends on how you view things. They are not _necessarily_ public methods on the class, but they are accessible via the interface (and thus _effectively_ `public` if you know how). I am not disagreeing with you - just pointing that `public` in the context of explicit interface implementation is a little more subtle than `public` in general.